# Maximum call stack size exceeded type nodeModule typeScript.js while configuring server side rendering with .net 6 and angular 13

Tags: server-side-rendering

I need to have a project with server side rendering with .net 6 and angular 13 . I configured it by following an instruction from a blog . But when I run my project I got an error below

> InvalidOperationException: The npm script 'build:ssr' exited without indicating success. Output was: > client-app@0.0.0 build:ssr > ng build && ng run ClientApp:server --watch Error output was: An unhandled exception occurred: error TS500: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at parseLiteralLikeNode (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30133:38) at parseLiteralNode (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30113:18) at parsePrimaryExpression (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:32289:22) at parseMemberExpressionOrHigher (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31776:30) at parseLeftHandSideExpressionOrHigher (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31770:88) at parseUpdateExpression (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31745:30) at parseUnaryExpressionOrHigher (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31665:38) at parseBinaryExpressionOrHigher (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31587:31) at parseAssignmentExpressionOrHigher (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31260:24) at parseArgumentOrArrayLiteralElement (D:\WafiSolution\NexTX\Project1\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:32349:176) See "C:\Users\DINAR\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-lVNzB3\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I tried to configure the project as a SSR but getting this error while running . But I could not find any potential fix